# WordPress with subdirectory for Nextjs

Tags: wordpress, next.js

I have a Wordpress site, I want to be able to run a nextjs prject under the path `mysite.com/nextjs`, is there an easy way to integrate a nextjs project under a subdirectory of a WordPress site?

Notes: I'd prefer to have the nextjs site hosted on a different hosting provider (something like vercel) - while the Wordpress is hosted on a normal VPS hosting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach but I've used it in the past to implement NextJS inside a wp site (like `wp-site.com/dashboard`)

Assuming you're using Apache as your web server you must enable `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html). See [this guide](https://serverfault.com/questions/500650/how-can-i-enable-mod-proxy-http).

Then modify your Apache's `sites-available` active file to include:

```
<Location "/nextjs">
    ProxyPass "https://separate-nextjs-server"
    ProxyPassReverse "https://separate-nextjs-server"
</Location>
```

Like it suggests, you must host your Next app somewhere as well. This is just designed to proxy requests to the NextJS server.

You can serve it in your VPS itself as well, that works but it kind of defeats the purpose of this method.

I like this approach because it allows me to keep my Next app separate from my wp one. Plus I can host it on Vercel for the first-class NextJS support it provides.

Comment: What about caching? And your WP server will still be hit a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to integrate a Next.js project under a subdirectory of a WordPress site. Here's a general approach you can follow:

1. Set up your Next.js project on a different hosting provider (e.g., Vercel).
2. Configure the Next.js project to build and export its static files. This can be done using the `next export` command in your Next.js project's build script. Make sure to update the `next.config.js` file accordingly if you have any custom configurations.
3. After building and exporting the Next.js project, you will get a static set of files that can be hosted on any web server.
4. On your VPS hosting, set up a subdirectory (e.g., `nextjs`) under your WordPress installation. This subdirectory will be the location where the Next.js files will be hosted.
5. Upload the exported Next.js files to the subdirectory on your VPS hosting. Ensure that the `index.html` and other generated files are placed correctly.
6. Create a `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory (if using Apache) or configure the server (if using Nginx) to rewrite the requests to the Next.js files.

   - For Apache, you can use the `RewriteRule` directive to forward requests to the Next.js files. Here's an example `.htaccess` rule:

     ```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^nextjs/(.*)$ /nextjs/$1 [L]
     ```
   - For Nginx, you can update the server block to include a location directive for the Next.js files. Here's an example of Nginx configuration:

     ```
     location /nextjs/ {
       root /path/to/nextjs-files/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /nextjs/index.html;
     }
     ```
7. Test the setup by accessing your WordPress site at `mysite.com` and the Next.js project at `mysite.com/nextjs`.

With this setup, your Next.js project hosted on Vercel or any other hosting provider will be integrated under the subdirectory of your WordPress site hosted on a VPS.

Keep in mind that this approach requires manual deployment and synchronization between your Next.js project and the WordPress site. If you make changes to the Next.js project, you'll need to rebuild and re-upload the static files to your VPS hosting.

Additionally, make sure to consider the SEO implications and configure appropriate redirections if necessary.

Comment: No way to utilize the vercel features like ISR then?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies.

Both of your answers in last hour appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.