# Can I connect a NextJS app to my Wordpress website using a proxy? as they are on different environments, but need to live under the same domain

Tags: wordpress, url, next.js, proxy, devops

I have a Wordpress website, which is a news blog type site.

On this website, their will be a tab for a directory, however, we decided to build this directory with NextJS.

The NextJS build has gone great, and working perfectly, however, we've now come to the URL connection side of the work and have hit a snag.

The WordPress site is in AWS on an EC2 instance, and the NextJS app is running in Amplify in AWS.

The end result we are looking for is:

Main site: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
Directory under same domain: [www.example.com/directory](http://www.example.com/directory)

So even though they are on different environments, could a proxy or some other method bridge the connection so the 2 are running under the same domain?

Thank you for your help!

So far, we have tried to use a proxy, but it causes the stylesheets to break and act a little odd on some URL's.

We also considered just moving the entire React code into a subfolder of the WordPress repo, but not sure if this is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but this helped me.
[WordPress with subdirectory for Nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75661819/wordpress-with-subdirectory-for-nextjs)
If this doesn't work, I recommend using nginx.